# How to create X number of elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

For an assignment in school I need to create a class that extends a "Wallet" class that has already been created. The contructor needs to accept an argument of how many credit cards this instance of your new wallet class will have.

How would I accomplish something like this in java using arrays?

Comment: `public Wallet(int numCards) { this.cards = new Card[numCards]; }` But don't use an array if it's not required by class rules. Use a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array size to the constructor, and then use that number in an array initializer:

```
public Wallet(int creditCardsCount) {
    this.creditCards = new CreditCard[creditCardsCount];
}
```